# Expose DNS entries via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I currently have the following setup:

```
# https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}selenium/hub:2.53.1-americium
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    environment:
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
      - GRID_DEBUG=false
  selenium-chrome:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}selenium/node-chrome-debug:2.53.1-americium
    container_name: chrome
    ports:
      - 5900:5900
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - SHM-SIZE=2g
      - SCREEN_WIDTH=2560
      - SCREEN_HEIGHT=1440
      - GRID_DEBUG=false
    volumes:
      - /tmp/
      - /dev/shm/:/dev/shm/
  tomcat:
    build:
    context: .
    args:
      ARTIFACTORY: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}
    container_name: tomcat
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src/test/resources/tomcat/context.xml:/opt/tomcat/conf/context.xml
      - ./src/test/resources/tomcat/tomcat-users.xml:/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

The above config sets up a selenium hub and deploys a webapp to a tomcat container. The resources that are served will have a href in the likes of *http://tomcat:8080/...*

If I want to access these resources via href from the outside, the tomcat DNS will not be resolved as the DNS is only exposed inside the virtual container network. One resolution would be to expose that internal DNS to the host machine, but I have no idea how.
Another would be to do a string replace of the href value and replace *tomcat* to *localhost* but that looks kind of dirty.

Anyone of you guys know how I can expose the internal DNS to the host machine?

Comment: It seems like you'd be better off configuring Tomcat to produce URLs that reference the physical host's name, or to produce URLs that don't include a host name at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze that would be an even better solution. Any idea on how I can achieve this without altering the code base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/
Exposing /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf